# dropzone.js file upload Maximum request length exceeded

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, azure-web-app-service, dropzone.js

I'm using dropzone and having trouble with uploading documents larger than 18MB. I keep recieving Maximum request length exceeded error and can't understand why. I have been researching this for a few days now and can't figure it out. Example of my configurations are below. Pulling what hair I have left out on this one.

dropzone js code:

```
$("#dz-documents").dropzone({
            url: "/upload/UploadDocument",
            maxFiles: 1,
            maxFilesize: 500.0,
            addRemoveLinks: true,  //*** 2/19/15 RKH *** changed
            uploadMultiple: false,
            autoProcessQueue: true,
            paramName: links,
            height: '150px',
            dictResponseError: 'Error uploading file!',
            init: function () {
                this.on("complete", function (file) {
                    if (this.getUploadingFiles().length === 0 && this.getQueuedFiles().length === 0) {
                        this.removeFile(file);

                        // reload documents
                        Documents.loadDocuments($('#hdfObjectId').val(), $('#hdfRecordId').val())

                        Activity[0].refreshActivity($('#hdfObjectId').val(), $('#hdfRecordId').val())
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

c#:

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> UploadDocument()
    {
        try
        {
            // The Name of the Upload component is "files"
            if (Request.Files != null)
            {
                OrganizationUser user = await ApplicationUserManager.GetOrganizationUser(User.Identity.GetUserId()); 

                // snipped validation code
                CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(Microsoft.Azure.CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("avnCloudStorage"));

                foreach (string name in Request.Files)
                {
                    HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[name];

                    if (await docRepository.Save(file, Request.Files.AllKeys, user.OrganizationID, user.ID, user.UserID.Value.ToString()))
                    {
                        return Content("Upload was successful");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return Content("Error occurred on upload");
                    }
                }
            }

            return Content("Error occurred on upload");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Error(ex);
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

web.config

```
<system.webServer>
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
</system.webServer>

<system.web>
<runtime executionTimeout="240" maxRequestLength="2097152">
<system.web>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you try this 2GB max:

```
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="2147483" executionTimeout="1600" requestLengthDiskThreshold="2147483647" />
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483647" />
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: That was it. I had it setup on the wrong runtime. Thanks so much.